# Implementing notExists in Hibernate Criteria in Java

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am working on some existing code where I have these 3 tables

**Table Inv**

**Table Prj**

**Table Prx**

Description of table Inv and table Prx is as following,

**Inv --> a,b,c,PrjId,d,e,f**

**Prx --> u,v,w,InvId,PrjId,x,y,z**

Now, I need all Inv records for which

there is no such Prx record present, such that

**Inv->PrjId = Prx->PrjId and Prx.u = 'some value1'**

I already have one Criteria on Inv based on some other attributes of the Inv table say a = 'some value2' and b = 'some value3'

so I need to add something similar to 'not exists' clause to that existing Inv Criteria. I was trying with **Subqueries.notExists** but it is not working properly.

It would be very helpful if someone explains the solution in details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of notExists(x) is "left join x where x.id is null", so in terms of SQL you would do something like

```
select inv.* from Inv inv 
left join Prx prx on (prx.prjld_id = inv.prjld_id and prx.u = 'some value1')
where prx.id is null
```

This is not hibernate critera of course, but maybe that helps you.

Comment: Thanks, @Wukash for your comment. But I actually require the hibernate Criteria only, I have the sql query, but as I said there are already many things in the existing hibernate criteria, I am just adding this part. 
Thanks though.